# How reduce space between shapes in ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I try reduce space between circles shape in a legend. How i do that?
I want to leave the circles almost 'glued'.

For example:

```
pd = ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length,
                      Sepal.Width))
head(iris$Species)

scale_pd = pd + geom_point(aes(fill = Species), pch = 21, 
                           alpha = 0.6,
                           size = 4)+ 
  labs(title="Iris dispersion",
       subtitle="Sepal length x Sepal Width per species",
       caption="",
       x="Sepal Width (cm)",
       y = "Sepal length (cm)") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Specie",
                    labels=c("Setosa","Versicolor","Virginica"),
                    values=c("#023047","#ffb703","#ef476f"))
```

I tried used

```
guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(22, 22, 22),
                                                 size = 10), keyheight = .1)
```

but does't work

Answer (score 2):

You can set `legend.key.height` to 0 in `theme`

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species), pch = 21, alpha = 0.6, size = 4)+ 
  labs(title="Iris dispersion",
       subtitle="Sepal length x Sepal Width per species",
       x = "Sepal Width (cm)",
       y = "Sepal length (cm)") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#023047","#ffb703","#ef476f")) +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `guide_legend()`:

```
scale_pd + guides(fill=guide_legend(
  keywidth=0.01,
  keyheight=0.01,
  default.unit="inch")
)
```

[image]